# Use stats inside Gnuplot inline functions

Tags: gnuplot

I can't figure out if it is possible to do something like

```
f_L0(FL)=(stats FL using ($8) name "L", \
   L = L_mean, \
   1)
```

Gnuplot keeps complaining: `')' expected` and points to `FL` inside the function.

Any ideas how to define some function like this?

p.s. my gnuplot is 4.6 (Feb2014).

**UPDATE**:
since this is not possible, it seems, i would just do some analysis in Octave and output it to the file :)

Comment: i know how to use stats, the question is = is it possible to use stats inside inline functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use `stats` inside of inline funcitons. Gnuplot functions are very basic and can contain only 'regular' mathematical function which compute a single numerical value. You cannot get access to data files inside of functions.

The `stats` command is command, which is the only command besides `plot` and `splot` which has access to data files.

The use of `stats` is as follows: You must use it as standalone command like

```
stats 'filename' using 8 name "L"
```

after which you have access to many variables which contain results from calculations on your data (column 8 in file `filename`). `L_mean` is one of those variables, for more see `show variables` after having executed `stats`.

However, you can do many calculations inside the `using` statement. To subtract the mean from you data, use e.g.:

```
stats 'filename' using 8 name "L"
plot 'filename' using ($8-L_mean)
```